# CKEditor Word2013 skin is not working

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have implemented my own version of CKEditor using javascript through modifying the default CKEditor with the help of `CKEDITOR.replace(editor1,....)`. Here's what my edited version looks like: [CKEditor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCiec.png)

Now, I just want to change the default skin to **Word2013 skin**. I have downloaded the zip file for the regarding skin and put it the **skins** directory. And I changed the code of `CKEDITOR.replace` like this :

```
<script>    
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {       
        fullPage: true,
        extraPlugins: 'docprops,preview' ,
        //extraPlugins: 'pagebreak',
        allowedContent: true,
        skin: 'word2013, /skins/word2013/',  // **Here I added the skin**      
    });     
 </script>
```

And I did this procedure following the CKEditor documentations available. Furthermore, I used `CKEDITOR.replace` so editing code for skin in default `config.js` would not be applicable here.

I have followed the official CKEditor documentations accordingly. But, It's not working anyway. Could someone help me in this regard?